# Is indexing the following columns efficient?

Tags: mysql, index, explain

I have the table: `orders` with the following columns

```
(orderNumber, orderDate, shippedDate, status, users_userId)
```

I indexed `orderDate`, `shippedDate`, `status` for performing similar queries to the following:

```
SELECT orderNumber FROM orders WHERE status='shipped' 
ORDER BY orderDate, shippedDate;
```

Since there are only about `14 possible statutes` for `an order` which I thought  would speed up the search whenever I need to select `range of rows of orders` with a `specific status`.

Also since `indexes are sorted`,creating an `index` on the `orderDate` and `shippedDate` it allows a `query's` `ORDER BY` specification to be met `without a separate sorting step`.

I just want to know if this sounds correct and if am I really optimizing my query in this way?

Here is the EXPALIN output of my query:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: orders
type: ref
possible_keys: composite_index
key: composite_index
key_len: 138
ref: const
rows: 1
filtered: 100.00
Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Comment: It pretty much depends on the actual data and benchmarking is the only way to know for sure. You can check the query plan for your current data and queries with EXPLAIN

Comment: Thank´s for the hint. I have just added above the explain output of my query.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT `orderNumber`
FROM orders
WHERE `status` = 'shipped’ 
ORDER BY orderDate, shippedDate;
```

Try a composite index on `orders(status, orderDate, shippedDate, orderNumber)`.

Comment: I would not index `orderNumber` since it's `UNIQE`.

Comment: It is OK to have `orderNumber in this index.  The way Gordon wrote it is optimal, "covering", etc.  More on creating good indexes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql